# Datagramsocket setSoTimeout

Tags: java, sockets, server, timeout, try-catch

I am currently working on a client-server application (for learning purposes) and I am completely stuck at how to properly set the DatagramSocket timeout and how to handle the exception.

Server-side looks like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(25000);
        running = acceptConnection(serverSocket, ready);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);

        while (running) {

            receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            try {
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println("Timed out...");
            }

            receiveMessage = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());

            ...

        }

    ... 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("");
    } finally {
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    ...
}
```

What i want to do in the event of the timeout is to go back to the main while-loop so i can handle another client. The server is designed to only handle one client at a time.

I have tried to add `running = false;` in the catch block but it did not work.

Comment: Please show the whole while-loop. It's unclear to see in which layer the catch-block lies.

Comment: I have now edited the post and explained. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: what about calling the method using guided recursion when connection timedout

Comment: To break out of the `while(running)` loop back to the `while(true)` loop, you should use the keyword `break` after catching the timeout exception.

Comment: You don't need to keep recreating the `DatagramSocket` inside the outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP did not now how to break out of the `while(running)` loop back to the `while(true)` loop when the socket receive timed out.

In the comments I told him to use the `break` keyword after catching the `SocketTimeoutException` and he mentioned this solved his problem.